# In CentOs 6.6 how do I get an interface up?

Tags: centos

I can see the interface with `ifconfig` but not with ip a. `ifconfig` shows no packets for eth0:1 The interface is down. how do I bring up eth0:1?

```
[root@monitor01 network-scripts]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxxx
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:feaf:5a5f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:168002 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:27741627 (26.4 MiB)  TX bytes:7852228 (7.4 MiB)

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXX
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xxxxx
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:febe:380c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3842 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:612375 (598.0 KiB)  TX bytes:297310 (290.3 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:31716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:31716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:12808506 (12.2 MiB)  TX bytes:12808506 (12.2 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your output:

```
eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXXXXX
          inet addr:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

the interface is up. However it is strange that you do not see the IP address on interface `eth0` when you run `ip a`. You should see a line like:

```
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx brd xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx scope global eth0:1
```

under the `eth0` section.

The following two methods should work to have the logical interface running:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 10.1.1.1/24 up
```

Or

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0:1
DEVICE=eth0:1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.1.1.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0

/etc/init.d/network restart
```

You can also add an additional address to the eth0 interface using:

```
ip addr add 10.1.1.1/24 dev eth0
```

Note that this address is not displayed using `ifconfig` nor `netstat -rn`

Comment: "Device eth0:1 has different MAC address than expected, ignoring." I cp ifcfg-eth0 ifcfg-eth0:1. I used the vi editor and changed the MAC address but maybe the UUID is causing this error and not letting me see the interface when I run ip a.

Answer (score 0):

ifup eth0:1

if it is a virtual machine, it is possible the interface is not attached. Use your vm software to make sure the interface is actually available to your virtual machine.

It is possible the interface could be connected to a different one than eth0:1.

When your server comes up and you run ifconfig -a, you should be able to tell by that output which eth file you need to set your IP in.

If you have the wrong HWADDR, as shown by ifconfig -a, in your eth file, that is going to screw you up. Make sure your eth file directives are correct and that the interface is actually attached.